# Show function is a continuous function - Vector Calculus

Tags: vector-analysis

I'm struggling to understand and how to approach this question, if you could give me a hint about how to answer it I would appreciate that.

So here's the question:

Show, by fixing the value of $F(0)$, that the following function $F(t)$ of a single variable $t$ extends to a continuous function on $R$ (real numbers).

$$F(t)=\frac{e^t - 1}t$$

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

A quotient of two continuous functions is continuous within its domain, and the only points not in the domain are those where the denominator is $0$.  It's continuous at $0$ if $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to0} F(t)=F(0)$.  So you just need to find that limit and then write $$ F(t)=\begin{cases} (e^t-1)/t & \text{if }t\ne 0, \\ \text{that limit} & \text{if }t=0. \end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks! I think the limit is 1 using L'hopital's rule? I am completely lost with this question :(

Comment: @AVelj : It can be done by L'Hopital's rule, but there is an even simpler way: $\dfrac{e^t-1}t = \dfrac{e^t-e^0}{t-0}$ $= \left.\dfrac{\Delta e^t}{\Delta t}\right|_{t=0}$ $\to\left.\dfrac {d e^t} {dt} \right|_{t=0}$ as $\Delta t\to 0$.  It's just a familiar derivative evaluated at $0$. ${}\qquad{}$